# Count input inside div and add +1 to each jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build slider and I have build everything right so far except I don't know how to count input fields with jquery and give each one incremented number when action is done.

I have 3 actions on my slide. Add slide, Remove slide and sort slides( for sorting I use jquery sortable to move elements up and down)

But main problem is to be able to save slides properly I need to have each field sorted by array number.

For example here is my input field in php page.

```
        $output .= '<div class="repeat-loop">';

        if( is_array( $values ) ) foreach ( (array)$values as $value ){

            $output .= '<div class="repeat-group">';
            $output .= '<input class="input" name="slideshow[0]" type="text" value="" />';
            $output .= '<a class="delete-row button" href="#">'. __('Remove') .'</a>';

            $output .= '</div>';

            $count++;
        }

        $output .= '<div class="repeat-group empty-slide hidden">';
        $output .= '<input class="input" data-rel="slideshow" type="text" value="" />';
        $output .= '<a class="delete-row button" href="#">'. __('Remove') .'</a>';
        $output .= '</div>';


        $output .= '<a id="add-slide" class="button" href="#">Add slide</a>';

        $output .= '</div>';
```

so when there are slides in database it will output

```
<input class="input" name="slideshow[0]" type="text" value="" />
<input class="input" name="slideshow[1]" type="text" value="" />
<input class="input" name="slideshow[2]" type="text" value="" />
```

and here is script that I currently use as a working

```
$('#add-slide').on('click', function() {

    //Get parent element
    var loop = $('repeat-loop'); // .of-repeat-loop

    // Count all repeat group div's
    var count = loop.children('.repeat-group').not('.empty-slide').length;

    //Add new slide
    var new_slide = loop.find('.empty-slide').clone(true).removeClass('empty-slide hidden').insertBefore('#add-slide');

    var input = new_slide.find('input');

    var input_name = input.attr('data-rel');

    input.attr('name', input_name + '[' + ( count ) + ']');

    });
```

But this only works when I want to add new slide it counts the number of .repeat-group and add +1 to the next slide.

The problem is that this just add +1 to number of slides

So if I have 3 slides I would have

```
slideshow[0]
slideshow[1]
slideshow[2]
```

and when I remove one slide let's say middle one than I'm left with

```
slideshow[0]
slideshow[2]
```

and when I try to add new slide the script will count again number of slides starting from 0 and add number to next slide.

so I will have now

```
slideshow[0]
slideshow[2]
slideshow[2]
```

What I need to do is to always count number of input fields whenever #new-slide, .delete-row, or .sort is triggered and change number on input fields so I always have like

```
slideshow[0]
slideshow[1]
slideshow[2]
slideshow[3]
```

So I can always save an array in database sorted out properly.

#### Small update

Thanks to OlivierH i figured out how to rechange numbers again when removing a slide now it's left only to figure out how to change numbers of slides when drag and drop slides to resort them.

This is updated code working so far.

```
$('#add-slide').on('click', function() {

    //Get parent element
    var loop = $(this).parent(); // .repeat-loop

    // Count all repeat group div's
    var count = loop.children('.repeat-group').not('.empty-slide').length;

    //Add new slide
    var new_slide = loop.find('.empty-slide').clone(true).removeClass('empty-slide hidden').insertBefore('#add-slide');

    var input = new_slide.find('input');

    var input_name = input.attr('data-rel');

    input.attr('name', input_name + '[' + ( count ) + ']');

    });


$('.repeat-group').on('click', '.delete-row', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();

    var loop = $('.repeat-loop');

    var count = loop.children('.repeat-group').not('.empty-slide').each(function(i){

        var input = $(this).find('input');

        var input_name = input.attr('data-rel');

        input.attr('name', input_name + '[' + i + ']');
    });
});

$('.repeat-loop').sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
});
$('.repeat-loop').disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate slide creation part from the naming part. You just have to loop on all slides and rename the corresponding input. You can do this at creation and at deletion of a slide. For example :

```
$('#add-slide').on('click', function() {
    createSlide();
    renameSlides();
});

function createSlide(){
    //Get parent element
    var loop = $('repeat-loop'); // .of-repeat-loop

    //Add new slide
    var new_slide = loop.find('.empty-slide').clone(true).removeClass('empty-slide hidden').insertBefore('#add-slide');
}

function renameSlides(){
    var loop = $('repeat-loop');
    var count = loop.children('.repeat-group').not('.empty-slide').each(function(i){
        //i contains current index

        //set input attr
        $(this).find('input').attr('name', 'slideshow[' + i + ']');
    });
}
```

You can see here that i created two functions to demonstrate this separation. You can call the `renameSlides()` function when to delete a slide.

**EDIT**

You can also call it when dropping a slide, by using `update` event:

```
$('.repeat-loop').sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
    update: function(event, ui) { renameSlides(); }
});
$('.repeat-loop').disableSelection();
```

Have a look at [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update).

**END EDIT**

I'm not sure that the whole code is working, maybe you will have to adapt `renameSlides()` function a bit.

Comment: Thanks man, this helped me a lot. Actually when adding slide i don't have to do anything. the script i posted is working well for that part because i just need to add new number in line when adding new slide. But when removing existing slide or rearranging slides mess things up. And your part of the code helped me to figure out how to have them ordered when removing slide. Now it's only left to figure out how to sort them again by number when i drag and drop them and reorder. I posted the update to the code working with remove slide.

Comment: You can use `receive` event of sortable and call `renameSlides()` function : `function inside. $('.repeat-loop').sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    receive: function(event, ui) { renameSlides(); }
});`. I have edited my answer.

Comment: receive didn't worked but using update instead did the trick.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved your problem. Please mark this answer as accepted in order to close the topic. Thanks.